# How to extract an numpy array from a csv file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For an assignment, I have to extract data from a CSV file using NumPy. The file contains multiple rows, but the first row contains the labels and looks like
`label, pixel1, pixel2, pixel3, ..., pixel785` - this one should be ignored.
The following rows contain a label in the first cell (some integer between 1-10, I believe), and the next 784 cells contain the actual pixel number values. These numbers have to be reshaped to be 28x28 arrays.

The function should return 2 np.array types, one with the labels and one with the images, and the output should look like this:

```
(27455, 28, 28)
(27455,)
(7172, 28, 28)
(7172,)
```

So far, this is what I have. I have managed to get the pixel values into 28x28 arrays (I think), but I am not sure how to go from there. The assignment suggests using np.as_type() as I need to turn the values into floats.

I have never worked with arrays in NumPy, so I am not sure how to work with them. Am I doing the first part correctly? How do I return the images and labels?

(Please stay within the constrains of the assignment when you reply since I am trying to understand all the concepts and suggestions, I don't want to be overwhelmed having to find other possible solutions since I am already struggling with this. Thanks!)

```
def get_data(filename):
  # You will need to write code that will read the file passed
  # into this function. The first line contains the column headers
  # so you should ignore it
  # Each successive line contains 785 comma separated values between 0 and 255
  # The first value is the label
  # The rest are the pixel values for that picture
  # The function will return 2 np.array types. One with all the labels
  # One with all the images
    #
  # Tips: 
  # If you read a full line (as 'row') then row[0] has the label
  # and row[1:785] has the 784 pixel values
  # Take a look at np.array_split to turn the 784 pixels into 28x28
  # You are reading in strings, but need the values to be floats
  # Check out np.array().astype for a conversion
    with open(filename, 'r') as training_file:
      # Your code starts here
        #training_file.readline()
        csv_reader = csv.reader(training_file)
        header=next(csv_reader)

        if header != None:

            for row in csv_reader:
                images=np.array_split(row[1:],28)
      # Your code ends here
    return images, labels

path_sign_mnist_train = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/sign_mnist_train.csv"
path_sign_mnist_test = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/sign_mnist_test.csv"
training_images, training_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_train)
testing_images, testing_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_test)

# Keep these
print(training_images.shape)
print(training_labels.shape)
print(testing_images.shape)
print(testing_labels.shape)

# Their output should be:
# (27455, 28, 28)
# (27455,)
# (7172, 28, 28)
# (7172,)
```

Comment: `row` is a list of _strings_, which you will first need to convert into some numeric type. I don't really understand why it was suggested that you use `array_split`, and you can also avoid mucking about with `as_type` by converting each element directly to a float: `image = np.fromiter(map(float, row[1:]), count=784).reshape(28, 28)`. Keep in mind you'll need to keep a list of all images, rather than overwriting `images` each time you read a row.

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` can load a nice `csv` - one with a consistent number of columns per row.  It's easiest with floats, but possible also with a mix of column types (producing a 1d structured array).  In your case you might want to use `usecols` to control which columns you load.  You can load different sets with separate calls.  Read its docs for more details.

Comment: yeah, I don't understand why either, but I was trying to understand how to use those functions. If you read the original question, I asked to please not suggest other ways of doing it since I am already struggling with the original instructions and want to understand how to make it work that way. thanks tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Think this will do the trick**

```
 def get_data(filename):
    # You will need to write code that will read the file passed
    # into this function. The first line contains the column headers
    # so you should ignore it
    # Each successive line contains 785 comma separated values between 0 and 255
    # The first value is the label
    # The rest are the pixel values for that picture
    # The function will return 2 np.array types. One with all the labels
    # One with all the images
    #
    # Tips:
    # If you read a full line (as 'row') then row[0] has the label
    # and row[1:785] has the 784 pixel values
    # Take a look at np.array_split to turn the 784 pixels into 28x28
    # You are reading in strings, but need the values to be floats
    # Check out np.array().astype for a conversion
    with open(filename, "r") as training_file:
        # Your code starts here
        # training_file.readline()
        csv_reader = csv.reader(training_file)  # None makes skip headers
        next(csv_reader, None)  # skip the headers
        images = []
        labels = []
        for row in csv_reader:
            images.append(np.array(row[1:]).reshape(28, 28))
            labels.append(row[0])

    images = np.array(images).astype(np.float32)
    labels = np.array(labels).astype(np.float32)
    # Your code ends here
    return images, labels
```